# How do you get urls to display with a slash at the end?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

There is probably a simple answer for this, but I couldn't find one, so my simpleton question is, how do you get urls to display with a slash at the end?

For example: example.com/page/ instead of example.com/page.html or example.com/page.php

I read http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php but most of it went over my head. I set expose_php to off, but the extension is still there, is this accomplished by editing something in the configuration file or in adding code to a php script?

For reference, I found the [mod_rewrite wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) helpful.

Comment: See the tag wiki for [`[url-rewriting]`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/url-rewriting/info). It's a webserver feature. You need RewriteRules and/or MultiViews for that effect. Php.ini settings are largely irrelevant.

Comment: Check out my answer @grasshopper, we can check if the URL has a `/` at the end, if not, append one by redirecting. :)

Comment: thanks for the answers, I'll be looking at some mod_rewrite tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mod_rewrite (on a apache server) (it's the better way than the PHP-Parser Variante)

example:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 3):

This is accomplished by adding URL-rewriting rules to your HTTP server, which will map incoming requests to *example.com/page/* to *example.com/page.php* for example.

Note that using a *directory style* name (with the trailing slash) can cause some problems when the client will try to access some files related to your page.

- When fetching *example.com/page.php*, if the browser encounter, for example, a CSS file to load, he will look for it at *example.com/**file.css***.
- When fetching *example.com/page/* he will try to load *example.com/**page/file.css***, since  you were not in the top level folder of the URI anymore. You'll have to add a [`<base href="http://example.com" />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag in each of your pages, making the *directory style* page renaming a bad idea eventually.

Comment: adding an extra line of code for cleaner URLs seems like a good trade

Comment: Using a *trailing slash* will make your URI looking like if it was poiting to a *directory*, which is **not the case** : for me it looks more disturbing than clean.

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean, initially i just wanted to get rid of the .php extension, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, at the very beginning you can use this:

```
<?php
    function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
     if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
     $pageURL .= "://";
     if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     return $pageURL;
    }
    if(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], -1) != "/")
        header('Location: ' . curPageURL() . '/');
?>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: and then after the redirection, how does the server knows it has to parse and send e.g. a PHP page to the client ?

Comment: I don't get you! Once redirected, why can't it parse? The question is `how do you get urls to display with a slash at the end?` Did my answer give a right one? At least something meaningful???